# my docker-compose couldn't work and show me "pkg_resources.VersionConflict..."

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my docker-compose was installed by pip as `pip install docker-compose`, My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

my python version is 3.6.9, pip version is most lasted and docker version is 19.03.5 .

Then when I try `docker-compose version`, i just get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (docker-compose 1.25.3 (/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('docker-compose==1.17.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3236, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3265, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/home/blackcat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'docker-compose==1.17.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I Googled many solutions but nothing like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed docker-compose with apt-get (version 1.17.1) and had a "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound" error.

I removed that version and installed another with:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and it does work for now.
Hope is helpfull!

Comment: If the command docker-compose fails after installation, you can also create a symbolic link to /usr/bin or any other directory in your path.

For example:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

Comment: Depending on the version, you might need to add 'v' to version.
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases